# Additional Parameter categories for Laravel API Resources

Tags: laravel, api

I'm learning `Laravel` and it's `API resource`. I'm trying to understand how to pass additional parameters as I have an extra category with my resource.

With `web.php` route controllers i'm able to pass my extra parameter to the method (although this is not RESTFULL) to deal with the query.

```
Route::get('store/{root}/{parent}', [CategoryController::class, 'subCategory']);
```

However with the `api.php` resource only looks for the `index` and `show` methods.

So i'm trying to achieve something like: `products/shoes/nike/{idOfNikeShoe}`.

Do I need to create a new controller `'brands'` and a new resource for this?

**Api.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1'], function(){
    Route::apiResource('products', ProductController::class);
    Route::apiResource('products.brand-type', ProductBrandController::class);
});
```

I'm confused as the routes from web.php can go to different methods but the api.php only targets `index,show,delete` etc

Comment: when u create resource u get all of the methods (index,store,show,update,destroy,edit, create). Then u can do same thing as before on controllers but just returning a response with a object. If this is not what u asked clarify whats bothering u better.

Comment: As clie1993 said api resource gives you (index,store,show,update,destroy,edit, create) routes. You don't have to use  api resource in `api.php` you can define route as you defined in `web.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if you have different requirement that is not exist in your resource route then you have to make one separate route for it method should be same but make another route like this:

```
Route::resource('categories', CategoryController::class);
Route::get('/categories/destroy/{id}', [CategoryController::class,'destroy'])->name('categories.destroy');
```

here I want to destroy object using Id so I have to make another route but method should be same you have to only change parameter of function.